# How do I name drop voicings

Tags: piano, terminology, chord-voicings

What is the name of this chord and what type of drop voicing is it?

Left Hand: C and G

Right Hand: Eb and G

Answer (score 4):

A drop voicing is constructed from top to bottom. You start by building the chord in close position, filling out some number of voices (usually four), and then "drop" the *n*th voice from the top down by an octave. (The root, we assume, is played by another instrument, or in the case of piano you can stick it arbitrarily below the rest of the voicing.)

But drop voicings are normally used for chords that have at least four distinct tones. Your example is a C minor triad in root position, and it's a nonstandard open voicing with a doubled fifth (we normally double the root instead). A more standard voicing would change the G in your left hand to a middle C.

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for your reply. If I changed the G in my left hand to a B, what would that drop voicing be in combination with the right hand?

Comment: If you consider the C as part of the voicing, rather than as an added bass note, then you could call this a drop 3 voicing for a Cmaj7. The "original" voicing in closed position had a middle C in the third voice that was dropped down by an octave. However, in practice, drop 3 voicings are seldom used in contexts where another instrument will be playing a bassline. It tends to generate a muddy low end.